# iOS Certificates disappeared

Tags: ios, certificate

Unbelievable, all certificates are gone!

App ID and provisioning profiles are still there. But now I can't renew the Distribution Provisioning Profile.

Why did this happen? Is there a way to recover the certificates?

[image: Developer account]

Comment: Just create new ones and update all of your provisioning profiles. It's no different than renewing them every year.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I probably have to create a new AppStore release then, as I'm using the distribution provisioning profile for a push notification service provider.